# AirPlay: Play Video on TV and audio on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, airplay

In my app I have music playing, through Spotify Music or Apple Music, coach voice playing and a muted Video playing at the same time.

Is it possible to play Video on TV and audio on iPhone or Video and Audio on TV ?

Comment: Could you please add the code relevant to how you are streaming the Video and the Audio on your phone/TV?

Comment: The code is actually in React Native. I use [Expo AV](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-av) for playing the Video and Coach. For Spotify I use [this](https://github.com/cjam/react-native-spotify-remote) library and for Apple Music [this](https://github.com/mtroskot/rn-music-player) library.  
For AirPlay I use [this](https://github.com/gazedash/react-native-airplay-ios) library.

If you have some code references how to do it generaly in swift or objective-c, that would also be helpful.